# PHP: Exploding array elements

Tags: php

I have a 2D array which I have exploded from a string. Once it has exploded this is what is output:

```
---> 0 - 16~4~0.0~~~~false~~~~ 
---> 1 - 1000.0~21.75~L~1~2.0~2.0~L~2~ 
---> 2 - 
---> 0 - 2~5~951.3~6.4~~~false~~~~ 
---> 1 - 1000.0~11.77~L~1~ 
---> 2 - 
---> 0 - 3~6~1269.02~5.1~~~false~~~~ 
---> 1 - 5.0~213.66~L~1~4.9~2.56~L~2~4.6~19.5~L~3~ 
---> 2 - 5.1~53.44~B~1~5.4~8.48~B~2~5.5~15.53~B~3~
```

I want to make it so that for each position in the array it only takes the first value before the ~. I am unsure how to do this. This is the code I have so far:

```
$test = explode(":", $string);
foreach($test as &$value) $value = explode('|', $value);
```

Just in case you need it this is the original string input:

> 1~1~828.32~12.5~~~false~~~~|1000.0~41.73~L~1~2.0~2.0~L~2~|:4~2~4.16~12.5~~~false~~~~|1000.0~21.75~L~1~2.0~2.0~L~2~|:9~3~0.16~24.0~~~false~~~~|1000.0~21.75~L~1~2.0~2.0~L~2~|:16~4~0.0~~~~false~~~~|1000.0~21.75~L~1~2.0~2.0~L~2~|:2~5~951.3~6.4~~~false~~~~|1000.0~11.77~L~1~|:3~6~1269.02~5.1~~~false~~~~|5.0~213.66~L~1~4.9~2.56~L~2~4.6~19.5~L~3~|5.1~53.44~B~1~5.4~8.48~B~2~5.5~15.53~B~3~:8~7~111.92~7.0~~~false~~~~|6.8~6.78~L~1~6.6~148.39~L~2~6.4~3.7~L~3~|7.6~128.0'...

I would like the output to be:

```
---> 0 - 16 
---> 1 - 1000.0
---> 2 - 
---> 0 - 2
---> 1 - 1000.0
---> 2 - 
---> 0 - 3
---> 1 - 5.0 
---> 2 - 5.1
```

Comment: I think I understand, but just to be clear, could you add exactly what the desired output looks like?

Comment: [strtok - Tokenize String](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to take each element of this array and trim off everything after the first ~ character. Building on your code:

```
$test = explode(":", $string);
foreach($test as &$value)
{
    $value = explode('|', $value);
    foreach($value as &$inner_value)
    {
        $inner_value = substr($inner_value, 0, strpos($inner_value, '~'));
    }
}
```

All I added was an inner foreach loop that inspects each value and removes the rest of the string after the ~ character.

Best of coding!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this should work:

```
$output = array();
$test = explode(":", $string);
foreach($test as $value) {
   $pipes = explode('|',$value);
   foreach($pipes as $cur) {
       $idx = strpos($cur,'~');
       if($idx > -1) {
          $output[] = substr($cur,0,$idx);
       } else $output[] = '';
   }
}
```

After this is finished executing, $output will contain the desired information.  You could also write a recursive function or use a regex, but both those solutions would be a bit more complex.

hth

Answer (score 0):

You could explode each line by **~** and take the first element.

```
$test = explode(":", $string);
foreach($test as &$value) {
    $value = explode('|', $value);
    $result = explode('~', $value);
    $first = $result[0];
}
```

But I think this could become quite inefficient if you only need the first element. A regular expression could be another solution. Like this:

```
\|(.+?)~
```

Matching every string after a `|` up to the first `~`. This breaks at the beginning of your string, but you could prepend that with a `|` for the regex matching.

Comment: That will cause a syntax error.  PHP doesn't allow you to get an offset of anything other than a variable.

Comment: @Casey Thank you. Over the years I've forgotton how PHP actually worked. :)

Comment: np, I wish php could do that, would make life a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to cut out a string part until a delimiter, then use [strtok()](http://php.net/strtok) instead of explode().

I don't quite get your current example. But it might be:

```
foreach ($test as $i=>$value) { 
    $test[$i] = strtok($value, '|');
}
```